# Calling a function from an external file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, calling-convention

Im trying to call a function from a different file in python. Im trying to process satellite images from Goes 16 in NetCDF format. Im extracting different values from the file necessary for the functions saved in a .py file called "remap". A piece of my main code goes like this:

```
from remap import remap
# Calculate the image extent required for the reprojection
H = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].perspective_point_height
x1 = nc.variables['x_image_bounds'][0] * H
x2 = nc.variables['x_image_bounds'][1] * H
y1 = nc.variables['y_image_bounds'][1] * H
y2 = nc.variables['y_image_bounds'][0] * H

# Projection Prameters 
lat_0 = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].latitude_of_projection_origin
lon_0 = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].longitude_of_projection_origin
a = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].semi_major_axis
b = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].semi_minor_axis
f = 1/nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].inverse_flattening

# Call the reprojection funcion
grid = remap(path, extent, resolution, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

In the .py file that I called "remap", the function is defined as:

```
# Define KM_PER_DEGREE
KM_PER_DEGREE = 111.32

# GOES-16 Spatial Reference System
sourcePrj = osr.SpatialReference()
sourcePrj.ImportFromProj4('+proj=geos +h=' + H + ' +a=' + a + ' +b=' + b + '  +f=' + f + 'lat_0=' + lat_0 + ' +lon_0=' + lon_0 + ' +sweep=x +no_defs')

# Lat/lon WSG84 Spatial Reference System
targetPrj = osr.SpatialReference()
targetPrj.ImportFromProj4('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')

def remap(path, extent, resolution, x1, y1, x2, y2):
... (and so on)
```

Now I have two different problems:

(1) My frist problem is that Im getting an error from the system saying:
"remap() takes 4 positional arguments but 7 were given", which I dont understand why is happening, because I already defined those 7 arguments in the function from the second file called "remap"

(2) My second problem is that I don't know how to call values from my original code that where extracted from the NetCDF file such as: "lat_0, lon_0, a, b, f, and H" to be used in the second file which are necessary from the beginning to used the function "remap".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see matplotlib anywhere here. Removing the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to your first problem:

How do you define the path, extent and resolution needed in remap()?

and to your second problem:

You don't need to call those arguments on the remap file, because from the main code your are calling remap and make the reprojection with those 7 arguments.